# Score for song possibly called "The Swiss Cuckoo"

Tags: identify-this-song, piano

I'm looking for the score to a song that I thought was called "Cuckoo Clock," but that is called "The Swiss Cuckoo" in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIlNBeEmPm4).

I don't know which name, if either, is correct. Does anyone know of a book or place I can purchase the score?

Comment: Is the song in the video the right song or not?  If not, remove it, it's confusing.  If so, then what do you need us to answer?

Comment: The tune is right, but I don't know if the name is correct. The guy who played the piano said cuckoo clock, but searches for "cuckoo clock" reveal a different tune. This video is the only one I found with the tune I'm looking for.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.  I'll edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Some research on the name Takács suggests that the composer is Jenö Takács. There is a website devoted to him and his life and music here :
http://www.takacsjeno.com/

From there (english language version of website), searching for solo piano pieces shows a piece called "XIX. Die Kuckucksuhr [The Swiss Cuckoo Clock]" in a collection called "Für mich [For Me]. Little recital pieces, op. 76 (1963)"

I wasn't able to see a sample of the music, as none of the online music sellers I found seemed to have it, but second-hand copies were around. You may have better luck with this extra information.